# Changing the Email Alert 'from' email address while using Workflow

Tags: workflow, email-alert

I have a `Workflow` in Salesforce and `email alert` executes when the condition written in the workflow met.

When `email alert` fires, the email always comes from the l**ogging users email address** (because of this unnecessarily getting lacs of messages), instead I want to set it like `no-reply@ABCSupport.com`. Because I want to show users that this is System generated email and no need to reply on this email address. No concerns will be taken care on this email address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution this problem. Since `workflow` is sending `Email Alert` as an `Immediate Workflow Actions`. We need to edit that workflow action and make sure **"From Email Address"** is selected to **"Default Workflow User's email address".**

Done !

[image]

Comment: Can we deploy the "Immediate Workflow Actions" ?